# Audio doesn't play in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have this code to get the audio inside my project and supposed to play audio:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self playAudio];

}

- (void)playAudio {
    [self playSound:@"Splash" :@"wav"];
}

- (void)playSound :(NSString *)fName :(NSString *) ext{
    SystemSoundID audioEffect;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource : fName ofType :ext];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath : path]) {
        NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) pathURL, &audioEffect);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioEffect);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error, file not found: %@", path);
    }
}

@end
```

I'm using iOS 8 with iPhone 4s simulator, and this code doesn't work and I not hear the audio, why?

Comment: Test it with an actual device.  I didn't hear a sound with the simulator when I developed the last app.

Comment: Thanks @ElTomato, this works on device, this version of xcode come with much problems....

Comment: Sounds seem to play just fine in other apps within the iOS Simulator.  Make sure you file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com if this is indeed a bug in the simulated runtime.  You should check for errors reported to the simulated device's syslog.